# How to compare each element in array and calculate percentage of how many are the same in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, function, count

I have two arrays:

```
aaa = ['hello','banana','apple','lemon']
bbb = ['fruits','banana','apple','pear']
```

I want to each element in both arrays (I mean I want to compare in order, such as comparing aaa[0] & bbb[0], aaa[1] & bbb[1]), if they are the same, return 1 and calculate the sum, if not, return 0,and calculate the percentage of the same elements, in this example, the expected output would be : 2/4

I wrote a function like this:

```
def check(a,b):
if a==b:
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

but the result of 'check(aaa, bbb)' is 0 since it compared the array in a whole, 
then I tried:

```
def result_check(a,b):
for i,j in range(len(a)), range(len(a)):
    if a==b:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

but gave me an error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

how can I get the result I need? Many thanks

Comment: Because this has invited two different responses, it's time to give another better example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ['hello','banana','apple','lemon']
b = ['fruits','banana','apple','pear']
equals = len(set(a) & set(b))  # & is intersection - elements common to both
result = equals/len(a)
print (result)
```

if you want to use basic for loop:

```
a = ['hello','banana','apple','lemon']
b = ['fruits','banana','apple','pear']

def result_check(x, y):
     count = 0
     for num in y:
             if num in x:
                     count += 1
     return count # function returns how much elements are equal

equals  = result_check(a, b) 
result = equals/len(a)
print (result)
```

output:

0.5

EDIT:

```
a = ['hello','banana','apple','lemon']
b = ['fruits','banana','apple','pear']

def result_check(x, y):
     count = 0
     for i in range(len(x)):
         if x[i] == y[i]:
             count += 1
     return count

equals  = result_check(a, b)
result = equals/len(a)
print (result)
```

or with list comprehension:

```
print (sum([1 for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] == b[i]])/len(a))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but I also want to check the element order, if a[0]=b[0], we count, not just if a in b we count

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use sets as in the other answer. If you wanted to get indices where everything was equal this might help as `ccc` has `True` or `False` entries only

```py
ccc = [el[0] == el[1] for el in zip(aaa, bbb)]
sum(ccc)/len(ccc)
```

Output: 0.5

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, you are missing indentation for your function declarations. Since you managed to get the unpacking error, presumably the actual code is formatted correctly and you copied it wrong. As for your code, there are so many things wrong with it, it's hard to know where to start: you are looping over two different variables (`i` and `j`) and two ranges when you should have one, you aren't actually using the variables in the loop, you're still comparing the entire lists within each iteration of the loop, and you're returning within the loop, which means that it will terminate during the first iteration.

The following would get a list of the results:

```
def result_check(a,b):
    result_list = [None]*(len(a))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]==b[i]:
            result_list[i] = 1
        else:
            result_list[i] = 0
    return result_list
```

But you could just do

```
def result_check(a,b):
    return([a[i] == b[i] for i in range(len(a)))
```

(This will return a list of `True`/`False`, but when you take the sum, they will be coerced to integers.

With the Pandas package, it's even simpler:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series(aaa)
b = pd.Series(bbb)
matching_percentage = (a==b).mean()
```